# Strong topology of complex varieties is unqiue.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I have a question about the strong topology of complex varieties from Mumford's "Red Book of Varieties and Schemes" (page 57):

[image]

He said the strong topology exists and is obvious that there is at most one such set. I know how to get the existence of strong topology. From the given topology on $k$, we can get the topology on $k^n$ by the condition iv) and v). For a variety $ X $, we can use the subtopology of $k^n$ to give every affine chart of $X$ a topology. Then we can gluing them to get the strong topology on the whole variety $X$.

But I don't know how to get the uniqueness of strong topology by conditions i),ii),iii).

Comment: If you consider a second strong topology, it satisfies (iv) and (v). Then for all locally closed affine subset of some $\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{K}}$ you have the equality with the first strong topology. Extending all these properties to a variety, you obtain that these strong topologies have the same local bases; and therefore they are the same (*id est* unique) strong topology.

Comment: @ronno I have posted my comment as an answer, adding some detail.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\tau_1$ be a strong topology, in particular one knows that $(\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{K}},\tau_1)$ is the $n$-times product topology of $(\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{K}},\tau_1)$ by (iv).

Consider a second strong topology $\tau_2$, then it satisfies all axioms (i) -- (v); in particular $(\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{K}},\tau_1)=(\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{K}},\tau_2)$.

Let $Z$ be a locally closed affine subset, one has $(Z,\tau_1)=(Z,\tau_2)$ by (iii).

Extending all these properties to a variety, one obtains that these strong topologies have the same local bases; and therefore they are the same (*id est* unique) strong topology.